# Javascript append keep adding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append `list[i].name and list[i].email` once every time sponsorListTree li is being clicked. I can append the  **`document.getElementById("name").appendChild(div_group);`** but the problem occurs when i click the div a few times, the same data will add up instead of displaying the result only once

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data){             
                var list = data;
                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
                $('#sponsorListTree li').attr('id', function(i) {
                    return 'sponsorListTree'+(i+1);
                });
                $('#sponsorListTree').append('<li class="button"><a href="#myModal" id= "investor" data-toggle="modal" >'+list[i].name+'<br/> <table class="data"><tbody><tr><td><span id="information" class="details"><br/><br/> '+ 'Email: ' + list[i].email + '</br></br> '+ 'Contact No: ' + list[i].contact.phone + ' </br></br> '+ 'Joined date: '  + list[i].date + ' </br> </br>'+  'InvestedAmount: ' + list[i].account.investedAmount + '</span></td></tr></tbody><table></a></li>');

                }
                $("#sponsorListTree li").click(function() {
                    var name = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
                    var details = $(this).find('span')[0].innerHTML     
                    var div_name = document.createElement('div');
                    var div_details = document.createElement('div');
                    div_name.innerHTML = name;
                    div_details.innerHTML = details;
                    div_name.className ="nameDetail";
                    div_details.className ="detail";                    
                    var div_group = document.createElement('div');
                    div_group.append(div_name);
                    div_group.append(div_details);
                    document.getElementById("name").append(div_group);  
                }); 

                $(".button").click(function() {
                    $("span").toggleClass("details");
                });

            }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style=" overflow-x: auto; width: 400%; height: 600px;">
        <li>
            <a id="root" href="#"></a>
            <ul id ="sponsorListTree">
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
<div id = "name" class="control-label"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you binding event handler in the `success` callback handler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript for loop on files FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012856/javascript-for-loop-on-files-filereader) <- it's about the scope of var and let

Comment: `for (i = 0` `for (var i = 0`

Comment: You say, "when i click the div a few times, the same details will appear." isn't that the intended functionality? If you are clicking on the same list item, the email of that list item will not change.

Comment: yes thats true but it keeps adding a new record each time i click on the div. I want the record only to be shown once

Comment: guys, the code above works and displays the proper results. The problem is it keeps adding a new and same data over and over again

Comment: maybe you need to clear `div_group` child before appending element, so every click will always reset the child of `div_group`. is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: doing `div_group.empty()` will clear all child element of `div_group`

Comment: Yes but now the code clears the whole div_group when I click it. It did not work. It is not displaying anything

Comment: it is saying div_group.empty() is not a function

Comment: @lowyat2017 Sorry I missunderstood your code. `empty()` is provided by jquery, if you want to clear child elements using pure javascript just use `.innerHTML = ''`. for example `div_group.innerHTML = ''` or `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = ''`

Comment: thanks @SuryaDarmaPutra, your solution works for me

Comment: you're welcome @lowyat2017